# There are multiple columns in my table. I need to extract some columns without writing column name in query

Tags: sql-server

```
Select [PPID], [Demand Class_User Data 32] as Demand_Class, [Discipline1] as [Product Group Discipline],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2015-11], [Net Sales Volume 2015-12], [Net Sales Volume 2016-01], [Net Sales Volume 2016-02], [Net Sales Volume 2016-03],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2016-04], [Net Sales Volume 2016-05], [Net Sales Volume 2016-06], [Net Sales Volume 2016-07], [Net Sales Volume 2016-08],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2016-09], [Net Sales Volume 2016-10], [Net Sales Volume 2016-11], [Net Sales Volume 2016-12], [Net Sales Volume 2017-01],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2017-02], [Net Sales Volume 2017-03], [Net Sales Volume 2017-04], [Net Sales Volume 2017-05], [Net Sales Volume 2017-06],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2017-07], [Net Sales Volume 2017-08], [Net Sales Volume 2017-09], [Net Sales Volume 2017-10], [Net Sales Volume 2017-11],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2017-12], [Net Sales Volume 2018-01], [Net Sales Volume 2018-02], [Net Sales Volume 2018-03], [Net Sales Volume 2018-04],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2018-05], [Net Sales Volume 2018-06], [Net Sales Volume 2018-07], [Net Sales Volume 2018-08], [Net Sales Volume 2018-09],
                      [Net Sales Volume 2018-10],
                      [Net Sales Value 2015-11], [Net Sales Value 2015-12], [Net Sales Value 2016-01], [Net Sales Value 2016-02], [Net Sales Value 2016-03],
                      [Net Sales Value 2016-04], [Net Sales Value 2016-05], [Net Sales Value 2016-06], [Net Sales Value 2016-07], [Net Sales Value 2016-08],
                      [Net Sales Value 2016-09], [Net Sales Value 2016-10], [Net Sales Value 2016-11], [Net Sales Value 2016-12], [Net Sales Value 2017-01],
                      [Net Sales Value 2017-02], [Net Sales Value 2017-03], [Net Sales Value 2017-04], [Net Sales Value 2017-05], [Net Sales Value 2017-06],
                      [Net Sales Value 2017-07], [Net Sales Value 2017-08], [Net Sales Value 2017-09], [Net Sales Value 2017-10], [Net Sales Value 2017-11],
                      [Net Sales Value 2017-12], [Net Sales Value 2018-01], [Net Sales Value 2018-02], [Net Sales Value 2018-03], [Net Sales Value 2018-04],
                      [Net Sales Value 2018-05], [Net Sales Value 2018-06], [Net Sales Value 2018-07], [Net Sales Value 2018-08], [Net Sales Value 2018-09],
                      [Net Sales Value 2018-10]

               From [dbo].[Sheet1$]
```

I need to call all the column name starting with [Net Sales Value 2018-08] without writing it. how should i do it.

Comment: Use the `sys` objects and create dynamic SQL.

Comment: i see there is only `ONE` column that is starting with that name `Net Sales Value 2018-08`

Comment: columns which are starting with Net Sales Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate dynamic SQL and execute generated statement:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE 
    @stm nvarchar(max),
    @err int

-- Statement generation
SELECT @stm = (
    SELECT CONCAT(',[', [name], ']')
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE 
        ([name] LIKE 'Net Sales Value%') AND
        (OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) = 'Sheet1$')
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
    'Select [PPID], [Demand Class_User Data 32] as Demand_Class, [Discipline1] as [Product Group Discipline]',
    @stm,
    ' From [dbo].[Sheet1$] '
)

-- Execution
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err = 0 
    PRINT 'OK'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Error'
```

Comment: Thank you  very much for the answer. The result is exactly my expected.

Comment: Hi @Zhorov, can i take this into a temp table.

Comment: @Sarita Just add `INTO #TmpTable`: `CONCAT(Select [PPID], [Demand Class_User Data 32] as Demand_Class, [Discipline1] as [Product Group Discipline] INTO #Tmp Tabel ...)`